# Unknown shape Tensorflow object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tensorflow object `(self.rec_fmap_clone)` and it has unknown shape during graph loading and has certain shape and value during running.

```
def __init__(self,fatness,image_shape, vocab, r_vocab, num_classes,rnn_cells_num):
           ......
           ......          
           self.rec_fmap_clone = roi_pooling(net, self.in_boxes, pool_height=self.poolheight, pool_width=self.poolwidth) #shape is (1, 20, 256, 1, 32)

           if not(self.rec_fmap_clone.get_shape()==None):
              self.rec_fmap = tf.identity(self.rec_fmap_clone)
              shape=np.shape(self.rec_fmap)
              self.rec_fmap=np.reshape(self.rec_fmap, (shape[1],shape[2],shape[3],shape[4]))
              self.rec_fmap=tf.transpose(self.rec_fmap, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])
           else:
              self.rec_fmap=tf.ones([config.train.input_labels_size, 1, 32, 256], tf.float32)
           with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d],normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),weights_regularizer=slim.l2_regularizer(0.0005)):
           classes = slim.conv2d(self.rec_fmap, self.num_classes, [1, 13])
           pattern = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(classes), self.rnn_cells_num)  # patterns number

       ........
       .......
def run(self, input_dat, in_boxes, labels):
        return self.sess.run([self.rec_fmap_clone, self.rec_fmap,self.global_step,self.learning_rate,self.loss,self.opt_loss],feed_dict={self.input_dat: input_dat, self.in_boxes: in_boxes, self.input_labels:labels})
```

During graph loading time, `self.rec_fmap_clone.get_shape() gave TensorShape(None). So the process went into else loop.`

But during running time, `self.rec_fmap_clone` has certain shape. Because I checked from the return value at self.sess.run and observed values.

```
return self.sess.run([self.rec_fmap_clone, self.rec_fmap,self.global_step,self.learning_rate,self.loss,self.opt_loss],feed_dict={self.input_dat: input_dat, self.in_boxes: in_boxes, self.input_labels:labels})
```

But the problem is during running, the process never goes into `if not loop and always goes into else loop.` Bucause sess.run output shows that self.rec_fmap is always 1.

During running time, why the process doesn't go into `if not loop`.

Comment: Found out that using `tf.image.crop_and_resize` is another alternate and more reliable solution than using RoiPooling. I'll test properly and update. `tf.image.crop_and_resize` is more mature and more reliable than RoiPooling.

Comment: Those who has similar difficulty. What I did was `self.rec_fmap_clone.get_shape().as_list()`. We need to change to `list()`.